# What do MBean parameters mean in collectd?

Tags: monitoring, collectd, jmx, kafka

I'm using JMX to monitor an Apache Kafka cluster with collectd's GenericJMX plugin. However, I'm not sure what some of the MBean parameters mean.

Particularly, I have one metric called `kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec`, showing the number of messages per second received by one machine. This is my configuration file for this MBean:

```
<MBean "kafka-all-messages">
  ObjectName "kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec"
  InstancePrefix "all"
  <Value>
    InstancePrefix "kafka-messages-in"
    Type "counter"
    Table false
    Attribute "MeanRate"
  </Value>
</MBean>
```

I don't know which `Type` is the correct one for this measurement, such as `gauge`, `counter` or another one. I've tried reading [this documentation on collectd](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Absolute) by couldn't really understand where I should apply each measurement type.

Could someone explain me it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally manage to get it working. Pretty much all Kafka metrics in JMX have multiple attributes. For instance, this `kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec` contains the following attributes:

- `Count`
- `EventType`
- `FifteenMinuteRate`
- `FiveMinuteRate`
- `MeanRate`
- `OneMinuteRate`
- `RateUnit`

When selecting the `Type`, you must choose whether you want it to retrieve the value as is or its difference for the interval collectd is configured to report metrics. Hence, `gauge` is the value and `counter` is the difference.

The most flexible way to report Kafka's JMX metrics is to simply use the `Count` attribute, a monotonically increasing counter that is incremented whenever a new message arrives, and report it as a `counter`. If collectd is configured to report every 60 seconds, this will be the number of messages coming in per minute. If it is reporting every 10 minutes, the value will be the number of messages per 10 minutes.

```
<MBean "kafka-all-messages">
  ObjectName "kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec"
  InstancePrefix "all"
  <Value>
    InstancePrefix "kafka-messages-in"
    Type "counter"
    Table false
    Attribute "Count"
  </Value>
</MBean>
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a gauge, by virtue of being a 'Per' value -- Kafka is already normalizing this into a particular time frame. If the name was just 'MessagesIn' I'd expect it to be a counter -- a number that continually increases as messages come in.

In other words, if the bean returns the 'right now' of something, it is a gauge. If it returns the 'total so far' of something, it is a counter.  MessagesInPerSec is a 'current state' value so is a gauge.